# Reaction of Silicon monoxide with alcohols

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecules

Elements from the carbon group tend to form compounds with two oxygen's. Let's say I want to produce $\ce{SiO_2}$ out of $\ce{SiO}$ by mixing it with some alcohol, for example:

$$\ce{SiO + CH_3-CHOH-CH_3 \longrightarrow SiO_2 + CH_3-CH_2-CH_3}$$

Is this likely to occur? at least before all the alcohol evaporates...

Comment: Alcohol evaporation wouldn't be a problem - it would react but hydrogen, not carbon would be reduced.

Comment: @Mithoron I don't understand you comment. What would then be produced?

Comment: Good luck finding silicon monooxide... What goes by this name usually is a very fine mixture of silicon and and silicon dioxide. Now, lower metals are a different story.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43103/why-sio-compound-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1):

I doubt very much its likely to occur.  Reducing an alcohol to a alkane is not trivial. strong reducing agents such as $\ce{LiAH4}$ cannot reduce alcohols, and to my knowledge $\ce{TiO}$ cannot reduce alcohols which would be an even better canidate that $\ce{SiO}$.

Comment: Yes, but relatively weakly reducing silanes can perform this reaction in the presence of acid. A major issue with LAH reducing an alcohol is the fact that LAH deactivates the alcohol to reduction by deprotonating it.